# <span> containing 3 overlapping images has 3x the necessary width

Tags: html, css

I have a  element, containing three overlapping images.  Inspecting the element in Chrome shows this:

```
<span id=​"span1">​
   <img id=​"img1" src=​"images/​progressbar.gif" width=​"120" style=​"position:​ relative;​ z-index:​ 3;​">​
   <img id=​"img2" src=​"images/​progressbar.gif" style=​"width:​ 120px;​ height:​ 12px;​​ position:​ relative;​ left:​ -120px;​ z-index:​ 2;​">​
   <img id=​"img3" src=​"images/​progressbar.gif" style=​"width:​ 120px;​ height:​ 12px;​ position:​ relative;​ left:​ -240px;​ z-index:​ 1;​">​
</span>​
```

The important point is that the second two images are given a relative position, shifting them to the left so they perfectly overlap the first.  But the span itself is still 360 pixels wide (3 x 120 pixels per image).  So how can I achieve this effect while keeping the span width tightly bounded around the images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that the browser's layout engine performs an initial layout (before taking into account your relative positioning), computes the `span`'s width (which is 3x your image width) and *then* moves the images to where you specify.

The obvious solution is to also do `<span id="span1" style="width:120px;">`. I think this is acceptable in your case, as the `120px` part (and its multiples) already needs to be specified to achieve the layout.

Another solution would be to give `position: absolute` to all images except the first (you will also need to give `position: relative` to the `<span>`). This would remove them from the layout and allow your `span` to snugly wrap around all remaining content (i.e., just one image). In this case though I am not sure how the `z-index` properties of your images (which have different `position`) would interact. Probably just fine. :-)

**Edit:** by using the last solution (and assuming there are no `z-index` problems), you can achieve your desired layout without specifying `120px` anywhere. This could be important, so keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is because relative works by moving the image after it is placed in it's normal position.